# Как задать движение объекта по кругу?

Tags: c++, sfml

Использую SFML есть круг и нужно сделать так, чтобы он перемещался по кругу. Но возник вопрос, как можно такое движение реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартная математика. Изменение координаты `x` и `y` в пространстве:

```
x=x0+round(r*cos(i*pi/180))
y=y0 +round(r*sin(i*pi/180))
```

`x, y` - координаты точки в момент итерации `i`. Всего итераций = 360.

`round` - округление,

`x0, y0` - центр круга,

`r` - радиус круга,

`pi` - число ПИ (3.14)

Comment: Я бы использовал не 3.14, которое быстро приведет к неприятностям, а `std::numbers::pi`.